# Query that joins just a single row from a ForeignKey relationship

Tags: sql, django

I have the following models (simplified):

```py
class Category(models.model):
    # ...

class Product(models.model):
    # ...

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    # ...

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_image_path)
    sort_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
    # ...
```

I want to construct a query that will get all the products associated with a particular category. I want to include just *one* of the many associated images--the image with the lowest `sort_order`--in the queryset so that a single query gets all of the data needed to show all products within a category.

In raw SQL I would might use a `GROUP BY` something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM catalog_product p 
LEFT JOIN catalog_productcategory c ON (p.id = c.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN catalog_productimage i ON (p.id = i.product_id) 
WHERE c.category_id=2 
GROUP BY p.id HAVING i.sort_order = MIN(sort_order)
```

Can this be done without using a raw query?

**Edit** - I should have noted what I've tried...

```py
# inside Category model...
products = Product.objects.filter(productcategory__category=self) \
            .annotate(Min('productimage__sort_order'))
```

While this query does `GROUP BY`, I do not see any way to (a) get the right `ProductImage.image` into the QuerySet eg. `HAVING` clause. I'm effectively trying to dynamically add a field to the Product instance (or the QuerySet) from a specific ProductImage instance. This may not be the way to do it with Django.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite a raw query, but it isn't quite public api either.

You can add a group by clause to the queryset before it is evaluated:

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(some__foreign__key__join=something)
qs.group_by = 'some_field'
results = list(qs)
```

Word of caution, though: this behaves differently depending on the db backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
catagory = Catagory.objects.get(get_your_catagory)
qs = Product.objects.annotate(Min('productimage__sortorder').filter(productcategory__category = catagory)
```

This should hit the DB only once, because querysets are lazy.

Comment: Thanks, I should have specified what I had tried. I have a query similar to this and while it puts in the `GROUP BY` and thus gets the right sort_order value, it does not get the image which is what I'm trying to do. Thus, the DB still gets hit when I need to show the image for the product. I was hoping there was some way to effectively add a ProductImage.image feild to the Product instance. I may do some DB redesign instead.

Comment: @MicahCarrick: I think that would work if you just add a `.select_related('productimage__image')`.